# how to deploy phar file on a webserver like xampp

Tags: php, xampp, phar

I am using maven with php and packaging my code to phar archive and deploy it on xampp. In java we copy war files for webapp folder of application server like tomcat. How do I do that in php? do i just go and put the .phar in xampp/htdocs folder ?

Thanks

Comment: RTLM? http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Apache that it should run `.phar` files with PHP:

```
cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf |head -n3
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(ar|p3?|tml)$">
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

See http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/phar-webserver.htm for more details.